# What is the formula that excel uses to convert number to datetime?

Tags: excel, datetime, numbers

When I enter a number (43547.44114)in an excel cell with a "General" format, then change the cell format to "Date" it automatically convert it to "3/23/2019 10:35 AM", I want to know the formula excel uses to do this conversion, and the reverse formula (DateTime to number) please.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as the number of days from Jan 1 1900, plus a fractional proportion for the extra hours etc But can be Jan 1 1904 - see below.

See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

And

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel